# -moz-transition title and text move asymmetry

Tags: css, css-transitions

I added `-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in` on hover. But in FireFox title and text move asymmetrically.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wkcpL/1/

Problem in `font-family`. When I remove `font-family:Arial;` from `body` or change `Arial` to `Verdana` attribute code starts to work correctly.

Why it works for `Verdana` but doesn't work for `Arial`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't comment on wh Verdana works but not Arial, but I'm thinking it has to do with using a `margin` for your transition. Give it a shot with `transition:transform(-1px, -1px);`.

Here's your fiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/jKHyu/

```
#content .block:hover{
    /* ... */
    -moz-transform:translate(-1px,-1px);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-1px,-1px);
    transform:translate(-1px,-1px);
}​
```